# a mistake in my regex pattern code in HTML

Tags: regex, html, forms

I want users to add at least 2 characters in textarea excluding whitespace

```
 pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+-=_:.&€£*%/]+{2,500}"
```

it doesn't work because users can add even one space and submit the form!

Comment: `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\-=_:.&€£*%/]+{2,500}" ` or `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+=_:.&€£*%/-]+{2,500}" `

Comment: " pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+=_:.&€£*%/-]{2,500}" , done but it doesn't work still.

Comment: The textarea tag doesn't have a pattern attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea This is why it is ignored.

Comment: That worked !!!! Thanxxxx.... I used minlength attribute

Comment: How about this `[^\s]{2,500}`?, God, I think i'm late sorry...

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `+` operator which means "one or more". I'm guessing that the `{2,500}` is then being ignored. Try changing you pattern to this:

```
pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+=_:.&€£*%/-]{2,500}"
```

Now the `{2,500}` quantity specifier says "must occur at least twice and and most five hundred times".

By the way, I've moved the hyphen `-` from the middle of your character class to the end. If a hyphen appears anywhere in a character class other than as the final character then it is assumed to create an interval of characters (such as `0-9`). So if you want to allow the hyphen to be matched it must be the final character within the character class.

Answer (score 0):

if you want at least two non-space chars, just use `\S.*\S`  as your matching regexp.  It will match two non-whitespace chars with *anything* in between. change `\S` for `[!-~]` if you want to use only ASCII charset.  Or as you did, put in the brackets the whole set of characters allowed.